# How can I configure things so that Jmeter finds the JDK of Java?

Tags: software-installation, java, environment-variables, jdk

I have jdk installed, in `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_212/`

I wanna run Jmeter, but this finds java in

```
./jmeter: 128: [: Illegal number: 
./jmeter: 192: ./jmeter: /usr/bin/java/bin/java: not found
```

`env`  shows this:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_212/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_212/bin/java:/usr/bin/java"
```

`/etc/environment` contains

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_212"

'#' JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre

PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_212/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_212/bin/java:/usr/bin/java"
```

How can I fix?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your java home is correctly set. It does not require to edit environment. Just remove `/bin/java` that is tailing after `$JAVA_HOME` at line no. 125 and 192 in jmeter binary file. Then try running `./jmeter` again.